# web api return message in response 200 OK

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, get

I am making an application in Web Api, with the GET verb.
In the process of attention to GET, I call a procedure to check for commands to send registered to the base.
According to the state of a conditional, sending commands or not, but I need to load in the body of the HTTP response 200 OK, a message if I use

`return "This command is null or error";`

Testing with Chrome Postman comes to me as a response in the body:

> "This command is null or error"

and not have to **get quotes**, for this change the response message HTTP 200 OK, by an exception.

The code is as follows:

```
private string ComandosAEnviar(int pPuntoMedicionId)
{
    MonitoreoEntities _context = new MonitoreoEntities();
    Comandos _comand = _context.Comandos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID_Destino == pPuntoMedicionId 
                                                                && a.Fecha_envio.HasValue == false);  // a.ID_Destino == _ptomedicion && a.Fecha_envio.HasValue == false

    if (_comand == null)  //SUCCESS
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        message.Content = new StringContent("This command is null or error.");             
        throw new HttpResponseException(message);

        return " ";
       // return "This command is null or error";
    }
    else  // si hay comandos cargo la fecha de envio y envio el string de comandos
    {
        _comand.Fecha_envio = DateTime.Now;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return "\nCOMMAND\n" + _comand.Str_Comando + "\n";  //envio la palabra COMMAND y despues el string con los comandos
    }
}
```

Works fine, but would like to see the possibility of not using an exception, probe in various ways and could not.

From already thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you haven't received an answer to this question, but have you tried the following approach?

```
public class MyController
{
    [Route("the/url/you/want"), HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("This is a string.");
    }
}
```